# X tick labels for timeseries in multiindex pandas plot

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series, multi-index

My original dataframe(df1) contains monthly data for five years. I do a groupby year and month as I want to plot the monthly variation of column 'sales' over the five year period (df_groupby). The resulting groupby produces a multiindex dataframe with index column as well as month column both named as 'Date' automatically.

```
df1:
            Dress     
Date                                                                  
2015-01-31  Suit
2015-02-28  Pant 
2015-03-31  Shirt

##df_groupby: to count the number of dresses sold in a given month per year
df_groupby=df1.groupby([(df1.index.year), (df1.index.month)]).count()

              Dress
Date    Date                    
2015    1   1   
        2   1   
        3   1   
        4   5   
        5   4
```

Now, I want to plot the number of dresses sold each month in five years as a timeseries such that the month should appear as minor tick lables and year as major ticks. I am trying this;

```
g= df_groupby
ax = g.Station.plot()
ax.set_xticks(range(len(g)));
ax.set_xticklabels(["%s-%02d" % item for item in g.index.tolist()], rotation=45);
```

This gives me a plot like this (I do not want the days of the weeks/just months and year) -

[image: Plot with undesirable x ticks]

However, I would like to draw a plot with x tick labels as follows:

> [image: Plot with correct tick labels]

**What would be a good way of formatting x ticks in such a case?**

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options I guess. One of them is to use `FixedFormatter()` as [tick-formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html).

Then you can pass your labels as strings and the new line character `\n` will result in a multiple line tick. To do this, you have to transform you ticks into strings first.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker


def setup(ax, title):
    """Set up common parameters for the Axes in the example."""
    # only show the bottom spine
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.NullLocator())

    # define tick positions
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1.00))
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.25))

    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    ax.tick_params(which='major', width=1.00, length=5)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', width=0.75, length=2.5, labelsize=10)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
    ax.text(0.0, 0.2, title, transform=ax.transAxes,
            fontsize=14, fontname='Monospace', color='tab:blue')

fig1, axs1 = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8, 2))
fig1.suptitle('Formatter Object Formatting')

# Fixed formatter
setup(axs1[1], title="FixedFormatter()")
# FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator.
# Otherwise, one cannot be sure where the labels will end up.
positions = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
labels = ['A\na', 'B\nb', 'C\nc', 'D\nd', 'E\ne', 'F\nf']
axs1[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(positions))
axs1[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(labels))


fig1.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: FixedFormatter]